# Filenotfounderror: [errno 2] no such file or directory: 'nsr001.ecg'

Tags: python, numpy, databases

I am trying to save contents of [physiobank Normal Sinus Rhythm RR Interval Database](https://www.physionet.org/content/nsr2db/1.0.0/) into a numpy array but I keep getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AverageRRI.py", line 20, in <module>
    averageArray = np.fromfile(file,dtype=float)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nsr001.ecg'
```

but the file does exist in the directory.

```
import os
import numpy as np

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('normal-sinus-rhythm-rr-interval-database-1.0.0'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".ecg"):
            print(file)
            averageArray = np.fromfile(file,dtype=float)
            print(averageArray)
```

When I add the pathname like:

```
averageArray = np.fromfile('normal-sinus-rhythm-rr-interval-database-1.0.0/nsr001.ecg',dtype=float)
            print(averageArray)
```

It works.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the root directory in front of the filename so that the full filepath is correct. For this you can use `os.path.join`:

```
import os
import numpy as np

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('normal-sinus-rhythm-rr-interval-database-1.0.0'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".ecg"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            averageArray = np.fromfile(os.path.join(root, file), dtype=float)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] **No such file or directory:** --->'nsr001.ecg'

The directory path you wrote doesnt have the file which you are passing, check the path.